# Django Tailwind Typography Prose not working properly

Tags: python, django, tailwind-css

I want to learn tailwind and I am using Django, but I occured a problem that typography isn't working, I don't know why.. because other tailwind classes works very well.

I am using that to run tailwind with django django-tailwind.readthedocs.io/

my html
`<div class="prose lg:prose-lg prose-slate"> {{ post.post_text | safe}} </div>`
my config tailwind contains in plugin section
`require('@tailwindcss/typography'),` that line that I know is necessery

How can I make that `prose` class works like it should?
Other classes from standard tailwind works properly.

I know also that css is generated for prose, and text is html with all  and others but they are without tailwind-css

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Problem occours only on Opera GX, since I changed to Chrome or Edge all is working properly.

Remember to active in devtools the cache clear.